# Vertical alignment in multirow environment

Tags: tables, multirow, shortstack

I'm using a `multirow` environment to span text over two rows. As it does not support `\\` for inserting a line break, I'm nesting it into a `shortstack` (see MWE below). However, the text is in neither of both cases (single line text, dual line text) really centered. What am I doing wrong?

**Example Image**

The red line indicates the center of the heading row (spans over two rows). As shown in the image, neither of both lines are really vertically centered.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Classifier configurations and their performance.}
        \label{tblClassifierConfig}
        \begin{tabular*}{1.2\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrllll@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{N-gram}\\as Range}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{\shortstack[l]{\textbf{Vocab. Size}\\in \#n-grams}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 2} \\ 
        \cmidrule(l){3-6} &  & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} \\ \midrule
        (2,4)-char                        & 500                                 & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5085         & 0.5849          \\
        (2,4)-char                        & 1000                                & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5114         & 0.6132          \\
        (2,3)-word                        & 1,500                               & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5134         & 0.6268          \\
        (1,3)-word                        & 2,000                               & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5138         & 0.6307          \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Never use `\shortstack` for serious work.

Comment: Can you give or refer to an explanation why `\shortstack` shouldn't be used for serious work?

Comment: Try, side by side, `\shortstack{a\\e}` and `\shortstack{p\\b}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `multirow` cells you also need to consider vertical space introduced by `\cmidrule`.  it is about `0.4` row height, so you can wrote

```
 \multirow{2.4}{*}{ ...}
```

i also suggest in columns with numbers to use `S` column type from `siunitx` package, not increase table width (it will protrude in next column). istead this rather reduce `tabocolsep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
             marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Classifier configurations and their performance.}
    \label{tblClassifierConfig}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                             S[table-format=4.0,
                               group-four-digits,
                               group-separator=\,]
                        *{4}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                                   }
    \toprule
    \multirow{2.4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{N-gram}\\as Range}} 
        & {\multirow{2.4}{*}{\makecell{\textbf{Vocab. Size}\\in \#n-grams}}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 1} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 2} \\
    \cmidrule{3-4} 
    \cmidrule{5-6}
        &  & {\textbf{Prec.}} & {\textbf{Recall}} & {\textbf{Prec.}} & {\textbf{Recall}} \\ 
    \midrule
    (2,4)-char  &   500 & 0.9999    & 0.9999    & 0.5085    & 0.5849            \\
    (2,4)-char  & 1 000 & 0.9999    & 0.9999    & 0.5114    & 0.6132            \\
    (2,3)-word  & 1 500 & 0.9999    & 0.9999    & 0.5134    & 0.6268            \\
    (1,3)-word  & 2 000 & 0.9999    & 0.9999    & 0.5138    & 0.6307            \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the table type addition! The table now is almost perfect. Is there any way to make the line below "Test Set 1" and "Test Set 2" as long as the whole column width? The line below "Test Set 1" is a little shorter on the right side, and the one below "Test Set 2" a little shorter on the left side.

Comment: @Patrick, just delete `(r)` and ˙(ll)`. i corrected code.

Answer (score 2):

A variant  with `\multirowcell`. The  `makecell`  package allows for line breaks in standard cells, and a common formatting (not used here).  Please note  your table is larger than the column width, so it will overflow into the column on the right. I loaded `caption` to have a sensible vertical spacing between caption and table. Also, I wonder what a `\marginparwidth` of 1.75cm means when the horizontal margins are set to 1.5cm.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=6pt}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm, bottom=2cm, hmargin=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \caption{Classifier configurations and their performance.}
        \label{tblClassifierConfig}
        \begin{tabular*}{1.2\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrllll@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirowcell{2.3}{\textbf{N-gram}\\as Range} & \multirowcell{2.3}{\textbf{Vocab. Size}\\in \#n-grams} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 2} \\
        \cmidrule(l){3-6} & & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} \\ \midrule
        (2,4)-char & 500 & 0.9999 & 0.9999 & 0.5085 & 0.5849 \\
        (2,4)-char & 1000 & 0.9999 & 0.9999 & 0.5114 & 0.6132 \\
        (2,3)-word & 1,500 & 0.9999 & 0.9999 & 0.5134 & 0.6268 \\
        (1,3)-word & 2,000 & 0.9999 & 0.9999 & 0.5138 & 0.6307 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `stackengine`, I change `\shortstack` to a long `\stackanchor`, but (importantly) also added a 4pt vertical buffer above and below the stack.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{S}{4pt}
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Classifier configurations and their performance.}
        \label{tblClassifierConfig}
        \begin{tabular*}{1.2\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrllll@{}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{\addstackgap{\stackanchor{\textbf{N-gram}}{as Range}}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{\addstackgap{\stackanchor{\textbf{Vocab. Size}}{in \#n-grams}}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Set 2} \\ 
        \cmidrule(l){3-6} &  & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} & \textbf{Prec.} & \textbf{Recall} \\ \midrule
        (2,4)-char                        & 500                                 & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5085         & 0.5849          \\
        (2,4)-char                        & 1000                                & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5114         & 0.6132          \\
        (2,3)-word                        & 1,500                               & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5134         & 0.6268          \\
        (1,3)-word                        & 2,000                               & 0.9999         & 0.9999          & 0.5138         & 0.6307          \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]